# What tanks have the most FOV?

Tags: diep.io

In Diep.io, the Sniper tree has an extra advantage since it has a larger field-of-view.

Are there any more tanks that have a higher field-of-view? Which ones have the highest FOV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Diep.io Wikia](http://diepio.wikia.com/) page on [Stats](http://diepio.wikia.com/wiki/Stats):

> 1. Ranger
> 2. Assassin, Stalker (this tier is slightly bigger than the Hunter tank)
> 3. Hunter, Streamliner, Predator*
> 4. Tied between different branches:
>
>    - Sniper
>    - Overseer branch (Overseer, Overlord, Necromancer, Manager, Overtrapper, Battleship, and Factory)
>    - Trapper branch (Trapper, Tri-Trapper, Gunner Trapper, Mega Trapper, Overtrapper, and Auto Trapper)
>    - Smasher branch (Smasher, Landmine, Auto Smasher, and Spike)
> 5. All other tanks.
>
> The Predator has a special ability that allows the camera to move away from the tank, allowing it to see further than its normal FOV could hold. Not all is visible at once, however.

## Conclusion

If we use raw FOV (without camera-shifting), you're looking for the **Ranger**.

[image: Ranger FOV]

Including camera-shifting, the **Predator** has the most FOV, as you can see almost one screen more in every direction, although not all at once.

[image: Predator camera-shifting FOV]